# PHP Form - download to zip

Tags: php, download, zip, file-upload

I have the following form:

```
<form action="download.php" method="get">
<input type="checkbox" name="file1" /> File1 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="file2" /> File2 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="file3" /> File3 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="file4" /> File4 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="file5" /> File5 <br/>

<input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Download!">   
</form>
```

I cant then GET the ticked value:

```
<?php echo $_GET["file1"]; ?>
```

Gives the result: `on`

However want I want to be able to do is select those options, and each option relates to a PHP file, on Submit each file is combiled into a ZIP

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What's different from this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019864/download-form-select-files-combile-into-zip

Comment: I dont know how to manage in PHP, specifically how to tell PHP which files I've selected in the form and whiere to get the files.

Comment: So you want us to 'give teh codez' then? No offence, but if you got no experience with PHP whatsoever, then it would be better to first get to grips with the basics. And that would mean to start reading the PHP Manual before trying to build anything.

Comment: @Viet The files are already on the server. There is no upload involved. See the duplicate question.

Comment: @Viet Is it harsh to quesion someone who solves a programming problem by asking questions on SO until each of the steps of his problem is solved by someone else. He could also do some more searching himself (or buy a PHP for dummies book)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add a value field to your form fields and change them to an array:

```
<form action="download.php" method="get">
<input type="checkbox" name="file[0]" value="1" /> File1 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="file[1]" value="1" /> File2 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="file[2]" value="1" /> File3 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="file[3]" value="1" /> File4 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="file[4]" value="1" /> File5 <br/>
<input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Download!">   
</form>
```

Next, in download.php:

```
if (!empty($_POST['file'])) {
    // open zip
    $zip_path = '/path/to/created/download.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive(); 
    if ($zip->open($zip_path, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
        die ("An error occurred creating your ZIP file.");
    }  
    // checkbox values dont matter because only checked boxes show up in POST data
    foreach ($_POST['file'] as $key => $val) {
        // generate filename to add to zip
        $filename = '/path/to/php/file' . $key . '.php';
        $zip->addFile($filename) or die ("ERROR: Could not add the file $filename");  
    }
    $zip->close();

    //===============
    // force download
    //===============
// assume you have a full path to file stored in $zip_path
if (!is_file($zip_path)) {
  die('The file appears to be invalid.');
}

$zip_path = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($zip_path));
$filesize = filesize($zip_path);
$filename = substr(strrchr('/'.$zip_path, '/'), 1);
$extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($zip_path, '.'), 1));

// use this unless you want to find the mime type based on extension
$mime = array('application/octet-stream');

header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.sprintf('%d', $filesize));
header('Expires: 0');

// check for IE only headers
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false))) {
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Pragma: public');
} else {
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
}

$handle = fopen($filepath, 'rb');
fpassthru($handle);
fclose($handle);


} // close $_POST check
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use isset($_FILES['file1']) to check if file1 is uploaded
2. Loop from file1 to file5
3. Save files from temporary paths to permanent ones
4. Zip them using http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php & http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php
5. Optional: Delete the uploaded files (using unlink)
6. Force download the zip file to the browser. See this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

It's quite simple. Enjoy!